# Is it possible to move a triggers such as BeforeDelete to a workflow or process?

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-flows

Is it possible to move a triggers such as BeforeDelete to a workflow or process? What would be the best/most optimal design for such a case? Process objects are triggered on creation and edit, but I would need one that just says delete. I also tried to scope moving the effort to workflows but did not see a way to move the logic to workflows either.

Comment: I have thought of a batch process, but is there a better way?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Triggers can only be moved to workflows if the trigger should have never been written in the first place (Click not code). A trigger is meant to provide different functionality than a workflow would for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows only trigger on inserts and updates. As such, you can't do configuration-based logic on deletes. This is one of the times when Apex Code is required.